# PhantomJs клик по ссылкам в цикле

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Вот такая функция делает клик по ссылке и потом сохраняет скрин страницы

```
function getInfoUsers(page, peers) {
    var element;

    page.evaluate(
       function() {
          function mouseclick(element) {
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0);
            element.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        element = $("a.md_modal_list_peer_name")[10];
        console.log("User: " + element.outerText);
        mouseclick(element);
    });

    window.setTimeout(
       function () {
           page.render("1111.png");
           phantom.exit();
       }, 8000
    );
}
```

ссылок на исходной странице 10 штук, при клике на ссылку появляется всплывающее окно, из которого нужно получить инфу и только потом сделать клик по следующей ссылке. Для начала пытаюсь хотя бы получить скрины всех этих окон.

Пробовал делать в цикле, но цикл пробегает быстрее чем успевает загрузить хотя бы одно окно.

Comment: Так. Вы пробовали делать снимки страниц в цикле (но он пробегает быстрее) и теперь, как я вижу, вы делаете снимки страниц по таймеру. Ну и... как оно?

Comment: сейчас просто делается клик по одной ссылке и делается ее снимок. Нужен совет как это дело правильно упаковать в цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю следующий алгоритм

```js
// если я правильно понял, есть какая-то входная
// страница, с которой нужно рекурсивно собрать
// все ссылки. Путь это будет она
var enterPage = 'http://somesite.ru';

// Далее предлагаю выбрать все ссылки с этой страницы
var enterPageLinks = [];

// затем нам нужна функция которая будет вызываться
// для обработки каждой ссылки
function openPage(url, callback) {
  // открываем полученный url и вызываем callback,
  // когда, вероятнее всего, страница уже будет загружена
  setTimeout(callback, 8000);
}

// и функция, которая будет делать снимки страниц
function capturePage(callback) {
  // делаем снимок страницы и когда закончим, нужно
  // будет вызвать callback
  callback();
}

// данная функция будет вызывать обработку каждой
// следующей страницы
function nextPage() {
  // пока в массиве есть ссылки
  if (enterPageLinks.length) {
    // вырезаем из массива первую ссылку
    var link = enterPageLinks.shift();
    
    // открываем её
    openPage(link, function(){
      // когда страница будет действительно открыта
      // мы делаем снимок
      capturePage(function(){
        // а когда снимок будет сделан, будет вызвана
        // следующая итерация и так до тех пор, пока
        // не будут обработаны все ссылки
        nextPage();
      });
      
      
    });
  } else {
    // обработка ссылок закончена
  }
}

// здесь окрываем входную страницу и выбираем из неё
// все ссылки, которые подлежат обработке и складываем
// их в массив enterPageLinks

// затем запускаем первый цикл итерации
nextPage();
```